# Matlab classify function for multi-class classification

Tags: matlab

What kind of Machine Learning method does the function "classify" in Matlab use for the multi-class classification? Is it SVM? If so, how does it use the classifier for multiple classes?

Answer (score 1):

It uses discriminant analysis, linear or otherwise. Discriminant analysis can handle more than two classes directly.